# Django Print Statement Security

Tags: python, django, security, printing

I'm working on a django project and have been using a lot of print statements for debug purposes (yes, regular print statements, not log entries). Here's a quick example:

View.py

```
def printView(request,x):
     print x
     return HttpResponse("Print View")
```

I was wondering if this is secure - I show a lot of data in my print statements and am afraid someone will be able to see the server output and hack my website. Can users see data that I `print`?

Comment: What i tend to do is put a `if DEBUG:` statement before prints, so that they won't show on production if i forget to remove/comment out when done debuging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All print data goes into console (logs), so it should be safe, except for some crazy configuration where print statements actually are sent to web client, but I can't imagine such case.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that they actually were in the log.